# Magento 2 - Ko Js - Multiple Instance of component in the same page

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I am trying to add two templates with the same component, but i need that each template do not share observables and computed this with the other template. I need each one have it own instance of the component.

Is it possible? i spend some hours and i could not find the solution even in this forum.

```
    <div id="inbox" class="inbox-wrapper" data-bind="scope:'inbox'">
    <div class="inbox" data-bind="click: toggle">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
        <span class="counter" data-bind="text: messageCount, visible: messageCount, css: pop" style="display: none;"></span>
    </div>
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
<div id="notifications" class="inbox-wrapper" data-bind="scope:'notifications'">
    <div class="inbox" data-bind="click: toggle">
        <i class="fas fa-bell fa-lg"></i>
        <span class="counter" data-bind="text: messageCount, visible: messageCount, css: pop" style="display: none;"></span>
    </div>
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#notifications": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
               "components": {
                    "notifications": {
                        "component": "Digibart_Notifications/js/component/notifications",
                        "template": "Digibart_Notifications/notifications",
                        "identifier": "<?= $block->getIdentifier(); ?>",
                        "options": <?= $block->getJsonOptions();?>,
                        "elementsId": "#notifications"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "#inbox": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
               "components": {
                    "inbox": {
                        "component": "Digibart_Notifications/js/component/notifications",
                        "template": "Digibart_Notifications/inbox",
                        "identifier": "<?= $block->getIdentifier(); ?>",
                        "options": <?= $block->getJsonOptions();?>,
                        "elementsId": "#inbox"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I think you'll have to select component on some condition like if this condition is met, run this component and if another condition is met run another component

Comment: No because i want to run both at the same time. The component is the same, but i need to run 2 instance of that component that have to be independent of each other ( do not share observable values etc )

Comment: @martin have you found the answer?